# Very basic -- adding ICONS to JQuery UI Accordion

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, jquery-ui, accordion

Do I have to use the Jquery CSS file? ... or is there some way to add icons without using that?

I hope I don't need it, because I'm doing this all in wordpress and enqueuing the Jquery CSS is a whole new lesson for me.

Sorry for such a basic question.  I'm a noob. If there's an easy way to add icons to my accordion please let me know.  Thank you.

Here's my code:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        active:"false",
        header:"h6",
        heightStyle:"content",
        collapsible: true,
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by creating and using your own CSS classes containing the images you want to use.  You set the accordian's 'icons' option to point to these custom classes.  Here's an example:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        active:"false",
        header:"h6",
        heightStyle:"content",
        collapsible: true,
        icons: {
                  header: "headerIconClass",
                  activeHeader: "activeHeaderClass"
               }
    });
  });
```

And your CSS classes:

```
.ui-icon.headerIconClass{
    background:url('/imageLocation') no-repeat !important;
    width:20px;  // make sure these sizes match your image size.
    height:20px;
}
.ui-icon.activeHeaderClass{
    background:url('/imageLocation') no-repeat -5px !important;
    width:20px; // make sure these sizes match your image size.
    height:20px;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. My javascript is exactly like yours above.  My CSS is as below.  The arrows just don't show up.`.ui-icon.headerIconClass{
    background:url("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/upArrow.png")  no-repeat !important;
    width:22px;  
    height:27px;
}
.ui-icon.activeHeaderClass{
    background:url("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/downArrow.png") no-repeat -5px !important;
    width:22px; 
    height:20px;
}`